# cakephp css issue

Tags: html, css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have one ctp file where my code is :--

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"><?php echo $this->Form->input('first_name'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('middle_initial'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('last_name'); ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td colspan="3">Phone Number</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('phone1', array('label' => false, 'type'=>'text','id' =>'phone1', 'maxlength' => 3)); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('phone2', array('label' => false, 'type'=>'text','id' =>'phone2','maxlength' => 3)); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('phone3', array('label' => false,'type'=>'text', 'id' =>'phone3','maxlength' => 4)); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my css :-

```
.contentWrp .input input{ height: 20px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid #12192c; font-size: 14px;}
```

[image]

But as you can see that on image it is using different css for textboxes.
Even I tried to give common css for that in my ctp (html) file but it takes different css..

Help me!

Comment: Tables are thought for tabular data, not for layouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP's $this->Form->input(...) generates its own html wrappers around the input control and also in the default installation includes a css file that styles it. You should try removing the default CakePHP css file first or view the source of the html generated and modify your css selector(s) accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 to you.Yes, It is correct...This is not solution for me but I got an idea because of that.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the CSS selectors are not correctly defined. You global tag like

```
input{ height: 20px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid #12192c; font-size: 14px;}
```

Comment: I cross check it is coming fine.. it is well defined also